# styling an asp:checkbox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, styles

I want to add some style to the checkbox itself using asp:checkbox in VB.NET.  Now all CSS I have found only works with input and I am using asp:checkbox and asp:checkboxlists and want to be able to style those.

Is it possible to do and do I do it thru CSS only or other methods.  I would prefer only CSS as my form is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS selector inheritance to specify only the  control of the rendered HTML. This will apply the style to all instances of input[type=checkbox] that reside within containers with a class of "myclass".

```
<style>
    .myclass input[type=checkbox] {width: 24px; height: 24px;position: relative;top: 6px;}
</style>
<asp:checkbox id="Checkbox1" text="the label text" cssclass="myclass" runat="server" checked="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

asp:checkbox renders like:

```
<span class="checkbox">
<label>option one</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" />
</span>
```

Apply **CssClass** property to the control like "checkbox" and create a css with that class name:

```
.checkbox{
padding:10px;
margin:5px;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
-moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to stylize the text or label of the check box...i want to style the check box itself.  Using your way, it styles the text or label.  How do I add style to the check box itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp:Checkbox **CssClass Property** to assign class to the checkbox.